# trigger functions when event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/hYarj/1/

I try to test something but end up with unknown error

```
function int_arr(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
numbers = [];
push4();

numbers.sort(int_arr);
$('#text').text(numbers.toString());

$('a').click(push1);

function push1(){
  numbers.push('1');

}

function push4(){
 return numbers.push('4');   
}
```

the click event did not fire..

Comment: 1) there's no 'a' element in your html 2) how would you know if the even fire ? Your code in push1 doesn't do anything visible...

Comment: your question not clear what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYarj/1/) I don't sees any `anchor tag` use '$('button').click(..)` like,

```
$('button').click(function () {
    push1();// push 1 here
    numbers.sort(int_arr);// sort after pushing1 
    $('#text').text(numbers.toString());// showing sorted text
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/dPwQA/)

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are calling the function `push4();` even before its declared !

these set of statements :

```
function push4(){
 return numbers.push('4');   
}
```

should be placed above this statement `push4();`

Answer (score 0):

It did not fire because you don't hava an `a` selector. Change the below line

```
$('a').click(push1)
```

to

```
$('button').click(push1);
```

and should fire the click event. That's another question what you do you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using is wrong the is no `a` tag here

```
    function int_arr(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    }
    numbers = [];
    push4();

    numbers.sort(int_arr);
    $('#text').text(numbers.toString());

    $('button').click(push1);//the selector is button

    function push1(){
     return numbers.push('1');//return is missing here

    }

function push4(){
 return numbers.push('4');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if http://jsfiddle.net/hYarj/5/ makes sense.

```
$('#text').text(numbers.toString());
```

got executed only once during the page loading. We have to call it manually again or attach it to some event, if we want to get the DOM updated.